# Casting JSON with ActiveRecord raw query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to make ActiveRecord to cast JSON values from the raw queries somehow?

Here's an example where I want to get `{"x": 1}` result to be casted as a Hash value, but I'm getting a String:

```
irb(main):017:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value(%{SELECT '{"x": 1}'::json})
(0.2ms)  SELECT '{"x": 1}'::json
=> "{\"x\": 1}"

irb(main):018:0> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value(%{SELECT '{"x": 1}'::json}).class
(0.2ms)  SELECT '{"x": 1}'::json
=> String
```

Please, don't suggest `JSON.parse('{"x": 1}')`. I need ActiveRecord approach.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need ActiveRecord approach"? What are you trying to do with the result? Do you have a model? What does the real query look like?

Comment: Have you tried ActiveModel Serializer JSON?
You can find more information here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html

Comment: @muistooshort I just need something on the ActiveRecord level, maybe implement type casting based on PostgreSQL OID or something like that. And I want to get AR make it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The low-level database interfaces tend to be a bit limited as everyone assumes that you're using an ORM. You could, however, trick ActiveRecord into doing the work for you as most of the database processing logic is in ActiveRecord itself.

ActiveRecord queries generally work with the result of a query more than what the model or table has to say so you can say things like:

```
Model.select('2*3 as six')
```

and the `Model` instances that you get back will have `six` attributes.

This chicanery also applies to `find_by_sql`:

```
> Model.find_by_sql(%q{select '{"a":11}'::jsonb as pancakes}).first.pancakes
=> {"a"=>11} 
> Model.find_by_sql(%q{select '{"a":11}'::jsonb as pancakes}).first.pancakes.class
=> Hash
```